# KVC and accessor methods

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos, key-value-observing

I have a understanding problem with one aspect of KVC and accessor method.

When I access my getter/setter methods with `self.variable`/`self.setVariable` the method `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` gets executed

But if I understand apples documentation correctly from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html)

> [...] and then uses setValue:forKey: to set the new value. This
>   maintains encapsulation of the model and ensures that any additional
>   actions that should occur as a result of setting the value will
>   actually occur. This is considered better practice than calling an
>   accessor method or setting an instance variable directly.

it should not get executed.

Is there something else that gets executed when I use `setValue:forKey:` which is not getting executed when I use the getter/setter methods?

What is getting executed when I use `setValue:forKey:` which isn't executed when I use the accessor methods?

Code example [here](http://pastebin.com/cUdPk0s0)

Comment: this is helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480432/kvc-setnilvalueforkey-recommends-calling-method-and-not-using-property-accessor

Comment: Show you code whatever you tried so far?

Comment: The link @Chancy gives is exactly right. This is specific to `setNilValueForKey:` (and other overridden KVC methods), because you don't want to switch from being inside of a KVC method to calling accessor methods. They might have been further subclassed, and caller may have called `setNilValueForKey:` intentionally (in particular, you might wind up in an infinite loop.)

Comment: This is a classic case of layers; KVC methods are considered more primitive than accessors. Accessors should call down, KVC methods should not call up.

Comment: @reformer I added code that uses both KVC and accessor methods with the same result.